# How to prevent a form from submitting on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop the Back and Refresh buttons from resubmitting my form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665399/how-do-i-stop-the-back-and-refresh-buttons-from-resubmitting-my-form)

I have a form that like most forms submits every time the user refreshes the page. Is there any way to prevent this so the form submits ONLY when the submit button is clicked and at no other times?

Comment: Duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665399/how-do-i-stop-the-back-and-refresh-buttons-from-resubmitting-my-form

Comment: @Gert you can vote to close for dupe

Comment: @Will - Not yet... need to reach 3000 in reputation. Soon. :)

Comment: @Gert all these rules sheesh.  Dunno how anybody keeps them straight.  Myself, I'm just winging it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182932/why-does-a-button-event-function-run-during-a-page-reload-in-asp-net

Answer (score 4):

the best plan is to do a header redirect after the form is processed.

e.g.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Even if you redirect to the same url, refreshing won't resubmit the form

Answer (score 2):

After the form is submitted, the server should redirect to some other page or even to the same page, but without any POST parameters.

Then the user can refresh the redirected page and it won't submit anything.